# Converting a const char * to a lowercase char *

Tags: c, char

I'm very new to C and I have this function that is supposed to take in a word and output it in lowercase. This is what I have tried so far:

```c
char *lowercase(const char *word) {
    int length = strlen(word);
    char *lower = malloc(sizeof(word));
    lower[length] = '\0';
    for(int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        lower[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    return lower;
}
```

This outputs ▒▒▒▒▒* for every word I enter.

Comment: `malloc(length+1)`

Comment: You need one more byte to store the NULL character.

Comment: Also ```length``` should be type ```size_t```.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE No that's not sufficient. The `sizeof` is completely wrong so just adding one is not going to help.

Comment: You need to use `malloc(length + 1)`.  You can't use `sizeof` for this, since you'll just end up with the size of a single pointer rather than the number of characters.  You should also use `size_t` for `length`, rather than `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(word))` is not correct because `sizeof(word)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)` which gives the size of a single pointer. You need to allocate enough for the string including the NUL terminator. So should be `malloc(length+1)`.